# CMake find_package messed up the include paths

Tags: cmake, debian

I using CMake 3.5.1 on Debian 7 for my project. Here is the code in my CMakeLists.txt

`find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)`
`message(STATUS ${Qt5Core_INCLUDE_DIRS})`

But the print out of ${Qt5Core_INCLUDE_DIRS} is
`/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5//usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5//mkspecs/linux-g++-64` which has no space between the paths.

What's wrong with CMake or is anything wrong in my CMakeLists.txt? How can I fix this?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`Qt5Core_INCLUDE_DIRS` variable is a list, that is a string delimited with `;`. When printing such strings, CMake omits delimiter and concatenates elements.

Use [list](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/list) and [foreach](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/foreach) commands to work with list elements.